# WinApi capturing messages in default proc is not "definitive"?

Tags: winapi

I can disable window movement by doing this in the message loop:

```
case WM_MOVING:
  GetWindowRect(hWnd, (RECT*)lParam);
  break;
```

This, however does not work if you remove the call to `GetWindowRect()`. Why ?

This looks like the message loop is only modifying the message in passing (`WM_MOVING.lParam` points to the destination `RECT` of the movement). The message still gets processed (by the system ?). Just doing a `break;` does not throw away the message, the window is movable.

The message is processed no matter what (even if you don't call `DefWindowProc()` on it), you can just set its `lParam` so that the window goes back to its initial position. Is there no way to discard the message completely ? And who's doing the processing ? (obviously, the system is, is there a ubiquitous `DefWindowProc()` up there in the sky - that you cannot turn off- ?)

What is exactly going on ?

Comment: The MSDN docs are a bit misleading, lParam points to the new proposed window position and you get the message before the window actually gets moved there.  By calling GetWindowRect() you force the window to be moved where it already is located.

Comment: Yes, that's what I gathered. Why is just ignoring the message in the default procedure not enough to skip the whole operation (move) ? The default proc does not pass the message to DefWindowProc(), but it is still being processed somehow (window is movable).

Comment: DefWindowProc() does not do anything with the message, it is not responsible for moving the window. It is typically sent by the code that implements WM_SYSCOMMAND(SC_MOVE).  Something you can see from the call stack with the symbol server enabled, albeit that the internal function names can be a bit confusing.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? If you want to create a window that cannot be moved (for whatever hostile reasons), handle the `WM_NCHITTEST` message and remove the *Move* entry from the system menu. If you are trying to solve a different problem, you need to be explicit about it.

Comment: @IInspectable : I'm just trying to understand how Window Messages work. Hans : who processes WM_SYSCOMMAND ?

Comment: So you are trying to understand message handling to put you in a position to implement the wrong solution to a problem? That's what your question looks like anyway. `WM_MOVING` is a notification, and while possible to change the actual location of a window, it is meant to be used for monitoring its current position. You know how to properly inhibit window movement already.

Comment: Why are you surprised that removing the code that modifies the rect changes behaviour? Have you read the documentation? Do you understand what the code in the question does?

Comment: @IInspectable : almost all of the messages you see in a typical message loop are notifications. These are the de facto standard of controlling a window behavior. As said, I am trying to understand how messages are handed about. Basically, my question is: who finally processes the WM_MOVING (because is does get processed, outside of the app thread and outside DefWindowProc). Not "how do I prevent moving", to which I obviously already have answer (you're right). So please help answer my question, or go about your day. Thanks.

Comment: If that is what you are after, see [Messages and Message Queues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632590.aspx) and [Window Procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632593.aspx). Not entirely convinced that the rudeness is called for.

Comment: I don't know how you perceive "please" and "thanks" as rude, but I apologize nonetheless. I just finished reading the "Messages & Message Queues" page and learned a lot about message exchange (especially between threads), but it does not answer my question. I'll read the "Window Procedures" page now. I guess I was hoping for a quick and satisfying authoritative answer, but it seems my question is on to something (that needs to be clarified).

Comment: I'm already formulating a concept : WM notifs are serviced by the system (call it sysWinProc), but it gives the application a chance to intervene, so sysWinProc waits on myWinProc/DefWindowProc before acting. About the only rational explanation to what I'm seeing here.

Answer (score 2):

`WM_MOVING` is one of calbacks done inside callig `SetWindowPos`. Window is moved after returnig from callback, and after finally moving window next is send `WM_MOVE`. There are also `WM_NCCALCSIZE`, `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`, `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGE`, `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`, `WM_SIZING`, `WM_SIZE`.

Some messages when routed to `DefWindowProc` do real work (for example `WM_NCPAINT`, `WM_ERASEBKGND`), some are used for gathering information for further processing (`WM_NCHITTEST`, `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`), some are used for notifying you about changes (`WM_MOVING`, `WM_MOVE`, `WM_SETTINGCHANGE`) or actions (`WM_COMMAND`, `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`). It is recommended that when you don't process message, you should route it through `DefWindowProc`. If you fail to do this for some messages that wouldn't have any effect, but for others you will miss essential functionality.

For modifying interactive moving or sizing of a window, `WM_NCHITTEST` is a good choice. You can disable default action activated by part of window, or implement selected action on any part of the window.

```
case WM_NCHITTEST:
    {
        LRESULT r = DefWindowProc( hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam );
        if ( r == HTCAPTION )
            r = HTNOWHERE;
        return r;
    }
```

Or try bellow code and see what happens when left or top border is dragged.

```
case WM_NCHITTEST:
    {
        LRESULT r = DefWindowProc( hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam );
        if ( r == HTLEFT )
            r = HTTOP;
        else if ( r == HTTOP )
            r = HTLEFT;
        return r;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel, the WM_NCHITTEST actually goes a layer up the WM_MOVING message and intervenes right at the mouse level. Very interesting. My question is actually about the destiny of the messages. Obviously the WM_MOVING is not processed by the app thread, nor the DefWindowProc(), so who finally does ?

Comment: @ExpertNoob1: Based on what observations have you concluded, that `WM_MOVING` were not processed on the thread that owns the window for which it was targeted? All message processing is strictly single-threaded, even in-bound cross-thread messages.

Comment: His reasoning is probably that window is moved when `DefWindowProc` handles `WM_MOVING`, but you can block both `WM_MOVING` and `WM_MOVE` by not routing them to `DefWindowPos` and window still can be moved.

Comment: Another way to prevent a window from moving is to handle the `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` message.  You can enable the `SWP_NOMOVE` flag in the `flags` field of the provided `WINDOWPOS` struct.

Comment: Let me try rephrasing Daniel's answer (hopefully I'm interpreting it correctly!): the answer to "who ultimately processes `WM_MOVING`" is "nobody, the message is informational only, no action is needed".  *Your* code can process it if it needs to, but if you don't, it just gets thrown away.

Answer (score 0):

The "[Window Procedures](http://Window%20Procedures)" doc says:

> For example, the system defines a window procedure for the combo box
>   class (COMBOBOX); all combo boxes then use that window procedure

I imagine that procedure belongs with the system (the appropriate system DLL, comctl32.dll I guess, unless you [subclass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633569.aspx#global_subclassing) it), but it executes in the app thread of course (after it loads that DLL). What that excerpt, and the apparent behavior suggest is the following:

- If the style you select requires a title bar, a title bar window (a
  system facility) is instantiated for your app, with its own
  windowProc, let's say "sysTtlBarProc".
- When you try to move this window,
  messages (system-created, starting from the input driver) are sent to
  both your app's windowProc() and to sysTtlBarProc()
- sysTtlBarProc() waits on your windowProc() (which can call DefWindowProc() or not) to return before acting on the message

This would explain the behavior: this protocol gives your windowProc() a chance to act (on its own) and/or modify the message, thus potentially modifying sysTtlBarProc's behavior. This is just a general concept, some messages I guess are purely informative (you can't change sysTtlBarProc's behavior for these), you can only monitor what's happening, and do something of your own next to what sysTtlBarProc() does.

This can easily be demonstrated by doing this :

```
case WM_SIZING:
case WM_MOVING:
    Sleep(1000);
    break;
```

You can then try and move/resize the window and watch the new "sluggish" behavior. Whoever is processing those two WM_SIZING/MOVING messages (you're not calling DefWinProc(), and you're not doing anything with the messages) is definitely delaying his work by a second now.

Comment: Title bar and border are drawn by WM_NCPAINT in DefWindowPos. Try `case WM_NCPAINT: return 0;`